# Is a polynomial normal ODE system solution a real-analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $t\in I=[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$, and
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} x_i}{\mathrm{d}t} = p_i(t,x_1,...,x_n), \quad i\in \{1,...,n\},
\end{equation}
be a normal system of first-order ODEs, where $p_i$'s are polynomial functions.

Since $p_i$'s are polynomial, we can always apply the chain rule to get a higher order of derivative with respect to $t$. Thus $x_i(t)\in \mathcal{C}^\infty (I),i \in\{1,...,n\}$.

My question is: does $x_i(t)\in \mathcal{C}^\omega(I)$?

(i.e. is $x_i(t)$ real-analytic?)

If yes, why?

Comment: What difference do you make between $\mathcal{C}^\infty (I)$ and $\mathcal{C}^\omega(I)$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $\mathcal{C}^\omega(I)$ means real-analytic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function
When the class is $\mathcal{C}^\infty(I)$, then it's not necessarily true that  the Taylor expansion converges for any neighborhood of $x_0\in I$.

Comment: The answer is "yes", if $\dot x=f(x)$ has $f$ analytic then the solutions are also analytic. This is often called Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @Artem Do you have a reference for this theorem?

Comment: Pick basically any textbook on ODE theory. Teschl's book is, e.g., freely available.

Comment: @Artem This is the Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem, isn't it? It says that if $\dot{x}=f(x(t)), x(t)\in(-a,a)^n\subset\mathbb{R}^n $ and $f$ is analytic near $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then so is $x(t)$ near $t=0$. Does it really solve my problem?

Comment: Yup. But in general Cauchy-Kowalevski theorem is the name for a theorem about PDEs. Look up Theorem 4.1 [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf)