# Kuramoto model has analytic solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-functions

I read a paper about a Kuramoto model, In this paper Kuramoto model has analytic solution of any initial value $\Theta(0)=(\theta_1(0),\theta_2(0),...,\theta_n(0))$

and the Kuramoto model is

$$\dot{\theta}_i(t)=\omega_i+\frac{K}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \sin(\theta_j(t)-\theta_i(t))$$

Here $\omega_i=\dot{\theta_i}(0)$, and $K$ is an constant.

How can we verify this Kuramoto model has analytic solution.

Comment: This is just general properties of ODE, if the right side is $C^k$, you get a $C^{k+1}$ solution, up to $C^\infty$. And if the right side is analytical in some radius, then you get an analytical solution on some, possibly small, time interval. This does not mean that you can also find a symbolical solution.

Comment: I want to study about that property, Please let me know what book has proof of this property?

Comment: In most cases, for instance here if you search for `[ode] analyt*`, analytical solution is meant to be a symbolic solution. However, I think in your paper it is used in the original meaning of "can be expanded locally into a power series". I wanted to know if you are aware of that difference. (It should be clear that the derivatives can be computed to any order, giving $C^\infty$, in question is if the convergence of the Taylor series, which would make it $C^\omega$.)

Comment: See the comments in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555385/is-a-polynomial-normal-ode-system-solution-a-real-analytic-function, the search term seems to be ["Cauchy-Kowalevski theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem) This then finds also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178696/theorem-about-convergence-of-power-series-solutions with another book link.